# Trying and failing to send an httponly cookie back to my refresh token endpoint using Jest and Supertest; is it even possible?

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, supertest, cookie-httponly

A coworker told me "httponly cookies cant be interacted with by the browser, hence you can't integration test anything with them." But someone in a Discord server told me otherwise: "httpOnly only means something to a browser. Jest won't care about it." I am unsure of this so I am testing it.

My goal is to send the httponly refresh token I receive from the login endpoint back to the "refresh the refresh token" endpoint, and receive a refreshed refresh token.

My expected result is that the refresh token endpoint will console log the token. My actual result is that the value is undefined.

The tech is Jest, Supertest, and an Express server.

Here is my code in the integration test suite:

```
import request from "supertest";
const api = request(server);

    // later in a test ...
        const loginResponse = await api.post("/auth/email/login").send({ email: signupPayload.email });
        // loginResponse is a success.
        const rt1 = loginResponse.headers["set-cookie"][0].split("=")[1].split(";")[0];
        const x = loginResponse.headers["set-cookie"][0]; 
      // can console log the refresh token cookie and its value here
        const refreshResponse = await api.post("/auth/jwt/refresh").set("refreshToken", x).send({});
```

Neither the "rt1" or "x" value works for the `.set("refreshToken", arg)` method. Both are undefined.

In my controller:

```
// where I set the refresh token: this is in a controller 
public async emailLogin(req: Request, res: Response) {
      // snip
            const cookieOptions = {
                httpOnly: true,
                expires: new Date(Date.now() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
            };
            res.cookie("refreshToken", newRefreshToken, cookieOptions);
            return res.status(200).json({ member, accessToken });
}

  public async refreshJwt(req: Request, res: Response) {
        try {
            const token = req.cookies.refreshToken;
            console.log(token, "refresh token"); // value is undefined!
            // ... continued
        } catch (err) { 
            // handle err
        }
   }
```

Have I been mislead? Is it impossible to use Jest and Supertest to integration test a backend that has an httponly refresh token cookie? or am I doing something wrong?

edit: I can console log the refresh token cookie's value: `refreshToken=a511d8a55839ee6a7d6102b3c0a184a432de160a3bd0e8a2c679e5fed272f3cac87eb17cfbff5af3; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 29 Dec 2022 23:33:24 GMT; HttpOnly 48rm`

This seems to indicate I can send it back properly. Yet I fail.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newb, the solution was to replace `.set("refreshToken", x)` with `.set("Cookie", [x])` and it works! Found my answer by reading the docs, of course. https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest <= ctrl + f `.set(`

Less messy solution:

```
const refreshToken1 = loginResponse.headers["set-cookie"];
const refreshResponse = await api.post("/auth/jwt/refresh").set("Cookie", refreshToken1);
```

The more important part is that *yes, you can send back an http only cookie using supertest, and view it on the server.* Hence anyone else wondering if its doable can find this post and have their answer

Comment: trying this and I get: "TypeError: this._header.cookie.split is not a function"

Comment: @Luis I had the same issue. In my case first request is returning multiple cookies as a string array. So, once I set `.set("Cookie", cookiesFromFirstReq)` it was passing an array instead of a string. I had to spread the first cookie array when I set it for the second request. `.set("Cookie", ...cookiesFromFirstReq)`. If you can pick the specific cookie from the list, just passing it also works.